# Android ListView OnItemClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I changed the layout of the entries in my `ListView` and now the clickListener is not working anymore and I don't know how to fix it and why it is not working anymore.

Here ist the code which fills the list:

```
private void setList() {
        List<Subject> subjects = datasource.getAllSubjects();
        ArrayList<HashMap> cards = new ArrayList<HashMap>();


        for (int i=0; i < subjects.size(); i++) {
            HashMap card = new HashMap();
            card.put("listname", subjects.get(i).getSubject().toString());

            long count = cardsource.getNumberOfCardsOfSubject(subjects.get(i).getSubject().toString());
            card.put("count", "Number of Cards: " + count);
            cards.add(card);
        }

         SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) cards,
                    R.layout.cards,
                    new String[] { "listname", "count",},
                    new int[] { R.id.CARD_SCREEN_NAME, R.id.CARD_TEXT}) {
                };

        listView.setAdapter(sa);
    }
```

I use the following XML file to define the layout of each entry (Choosed to make it that way because I wanted to add Sub Items):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- A row of tweet data for display -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CARD_SCREEN_NAME"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AndroidZA"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/CARD_TEXT"
            android:text="Hi, this is a tweet. It should be 140 characters or less"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my Click Listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Object item = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                selectedItem = item.toString();

                goToDelete();
            }


        });
```

here is the `goToDelete()`-Method which I use to go to the new `Acitity`. I pass a `String` with the `Intent` because I need informations about the selected subject in the upcoming `Activity`. THe problem could be that I dont get these informations right in my ClickListener:

```
Object item = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
selectedItem = item.toString();
```

But even without that the `goToDelete()` is not called. Can someone help me with this problem? If you need any more informations, let me know!

Comment: Use listview.setonitemclicklistener() method to click on list item.

Comment: Debugging it to isolate where the problem may be would help

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Is it crashing? Have you set a breakpoint in the `onItemClick()` to see if it ever gets control? Etc...

Comment: And what your logcat says?

Comment: I just figuered out: The onItemClickListener is called, but it stops working on this line: Object item = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

Comment: I think the problem is that i can't identify a item any longer this way because i dont use the default layout.. Before i changed it it was a normal list. This way I could get the information like i wrote in the original post

Comment: LogCat is finde - no crashes

Comment: What do you mean "it stops working"?  Does getItem() return the right item or does it crash somehow or what?

Comment: no the code below that statement is not executed. The problem is: I dont know what getItem returns now that i changed the list to a custom layout. before that i could get the list item and with .toString i wrote it into a String variable...

Comment: You say that your goToDelete() method isn't firing.  Perhaps you onClickItemListener is firing either.  Add log statements at each point to see where the bottleneck is.  Or step through in debug.  Also, post your full code.  Is this an Activity or Fragment.

Comment: Still don't follow you.  Either it will execute the statement below or something threw an exception.  If you're in the debugger, you'll get a trace output (or you can grab the log file off your device).  Also, if you're in the debugger, you can see the type of object returned -- it shows you that and lets you drill down and see all the member variables.